# PCgen domain specific spells

Tags: pathfinder-1e, tools, pcgen

I'm new to pathfinder rpg and pcgen tool, and I'm trying to get a feel of game mechanic using pcgen generator and gmgen combat tool (initiative).

I've created 1-st level cleric and can't figure out how to use domain specific spells, say I chose Gorum as my deity and war & strength as domains, so I should receive two spells -- Battle rage and Strength surge. I can see them in my pdf character sheet, but there is no reference of them among my spells in gmgen combat section.

Is there a way to use them?

Comment: What do you mean by "using them"? Applying their effects to a character for example? If so, quick answer: it's done through Temporary Bonuses.

Comment: Yes, apply them to another PC while being in combat (You can touch a creature as a standard action to give it a +1 bonus on melee damage rolls for 1 round. You can do so 4 times per day).

Unfortunately there are no such temporary bonuses, but it could be the solution if there were.

Comment: Have you read the Pathfinder rules? Playing around with PCGen won't teach you how combat works or how casting spells works, because those are not part of creating a character.

Comment: I've red books from  beginner's box. And was trying to play around with the rules I've just learned. I'm also looking through the core rules book, but just scrap the surface.

Comment: One thing to understand is that PCGen is mostly meant to help creating (and maintaining) characters. It does have a few GM tools for combat, but in general it won't do absolutely everything for you. It is not a full gaming engine in that sense. Also, considering the mass of data and rules in Pathfinder, it's generally recommended to first try to understand from the books, and *then* use PCGen to help you build things. Or at least keep referring to the official books rather than take PCGen's word for anything :)

Comment: Thank you for care and explanations. That is exactly what I trying to do :) read books and playing with rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that at the moment, these domains do not provide any sort of Temporary Bonuses related to their powers. This is not a rare case as many things in Pathfinder provide temporary bonuses, and often context-specific ones.

The data crew usually focuses on permanent bonuses first, and then tries to add temporary bonuses whenever possible. Being a voluntary effort and based on a massive set of rules, it's often the case that such bonuses are forgotten and not implemented.

In general, proceed as such:

- Check the official Pathfinder rules to get a sense of how things work, if only to spot a potential bug or missing effects in PCGen.
- If an ability should give a permanent bonus but does not, make sure the character truly matches all the pre-requisites (class, race, skill values and oh-so-many other possible things).
- If an ability should give a bonus that is obviously temporary or context-related, check the Temporary Bonuses tab list to see if it's in there.
- If the permanent bonus is not given or a Temporary Bonus does not exist, you can:

  - Post on [PCGen's Jira](http://jira.pcgen.org). Temporary Bonuses would be classified as Data Feature requests, while missing permanent bonuses (or wrongly applied temporary bonuses) would be a Data Bug
  - Post on the [PCGen mailing list](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/pcgen/info) to ask if it's indeed a bug, or something else. Do note that if it is a bug, you will be asked to post it on the Jira so the issue can be followed appropriately and prioritized. Folks are usually pretty fast at fixing things though, so I'd say it's worth it.

To save you the trouble, I posted [this one on the Jira](http://jira.pcgen.org/browse/DATA-1492).